# strtotime(nth [day] of [month] [year])

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
<?php
  $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("fourth monday april ". date("Y", strtotime("2013-04-01"))));     
  echo $endDate
?>
```

Why does this ouput 2013-04-29 when the correct answer is 2013-04-22?

Anytime the day you are searching for happens to fall on the first of a month, the day counter (i.e. "fourth") always displays one more than it should.

Example:  "third wednesday may 2013" outputs 2013-05-22 when it should be 2013-05-15.

I am guessing the quick way to fix this would be to see if the first day of the month is the same day you are looking for and decrease the day counter ("fourth", "third" etc.) accordingly?

Comment: Perhaps you because you have specified Year, Month, Date?

Comment: Just assuming, but it is probably interpreting "fourth monday after 2013-04-01"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the phrasing to:

`fouth monday of april ". date("Y", strtotime("2013-04-01"))`

The key being `of`.

Comment: Funny because the title actually says `nth [day] **of** [month] [year]` and yet `of` is the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfect.  Some of the examples I saw in the PHP Manual omitted the of, so that's what I did.  Turns out the manual was nothing but lies.

Answer (score -1):

If other ones also looking for answer here for `nth` day, for example 15. day of last month:

`date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("first day of previous month") ).' + 14 days') );`